# How to install package with -t option from ppa

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'am running ubuntu xenial in virtualbox.

I bound some PPAs in my System with apt-pinning. An Example

```
cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/xbmc 
# Apt-pinning für ppa:xbmc

Package: *
Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
Pin-Priority: 50
```

How can I install kodi with

```
apt install -t something kodi


LANG=C apt install -t team-xbmc kodi
Reading package lists... Done
E: The value 'team-xbmc' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources
```

I tried several entries in /etc/apt/preferences/xbmc

```
LANG=C apt-cache policy | grep -i xbmc -A1
      50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
         release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-team-xbmc,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Kodi stable,c=main,b=i386 
origin ppa.launchpad.net
```

and several options for `-t`. But the result is always the same.

I know I can install kodi from the ppa by giving the exact version of the package, but this is circuitous.

Comment: The `-t` expects a release name or, I think, a package version. Did you try with one of those? `team-xbmc` is neither.

Comment: Thanks, but package version I will avoid.  There mußt be a way similiar to in Debian `apt install -t jessie-backports something` i will show in `/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_team-xbmc_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_InRelease` Maybe is this helpfull

Comment: Why do you want to use `-t`? Doesn’t `apt install kodi` work without any other option? Have you read the documentation of the `-t` option?

Comment: Ah, I thought  because of the low pin priority form the ppa, that `apt install kodi` will draw the packages from xenial/universe. To complicated   thinking. I'm ashamed of oneself.

Comment: I was right `fetch:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 kodi` it draws from universe.

Comment: can someone investigate if this really work? `apt -d -t xenial install kodi fetch:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 kodi-bin i386 2:17.0~git20170210.1529-final-0xenial [12,8 MB]`
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked it with 2 ppa's which are containing packages, that also      available  in "official sources"

```
sudo apt-get -t xenial install kodi
```

draws Packages from ppa.

```
sudo apt install kodi
```

draws it from universe. I don't know why, but it works this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
# apt-get install kodi=<exact version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use apt-cache policy to know which version of kodi package is from where. Here I'm using youtube-dl for the same effect.

```
[$] apt-cache policy youtube-dl                                                                                                    
youtube-dl:
  Installed: 2017.02.07-1
  Candidate: 2017.02.07-1
  Version table:
     2017.03.07-1 1
          1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
          1 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable/main i386 Packages
 *** 2017.02.07-1 600
        600 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        600 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As can be seen it tells me that I have two options, one from stretch/testing, the other from sid/unstable. If I had option of another repo, it would have given that as well.

In Debian, the reason you can use `- t` and give backports, that's because in debian,, apt understands that there is repo. called backports and it has been well-defined for number of years. There are third-party repos for Debian as well (for e.g. deb-multimedia) where if you want their version, you will have to take its name. Whatever I have seen either of backport packages or third-party repos, most of them have unique naming scheme which differs from Debian official package and version naming procedure.

All or any third-party repos. for Ubuntu don't necessarily lie in/at Launchpad hence the need for exact name and version to help find what is needed.